# Redirect to item page after deleteView in class based views

Tags: django

I have an invoice page with each invoice (factuur) has items in it (relation invoice-items with ForeignKey). When I delete one of the items with the class based deleteView I want to redirect back to the specific invoice id with the remaining items in it.

urls.py:

```
path('factuur/<factuur_id>', views.facturen_detail_view, name='facturen_detail_view'),
path('delete/<int:pk>', views.FactuurItemDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_factuurItem'),
```

views.py:

```
class FactuurItemDeleteView(BSModalDeleteView):
    model = FactuurItems
    template_name = 'delete_fitem.html'
    success_message = 'Succes: factuur item is verwijderd.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('facturen_detail_view')
```

So what I want is redirect it to /factuur/factuur_id after deletion (where I was at the moment of clicking the delete button). But how do I redirect as I need to know invoice id (factuur_id) in the first place. I don't know how to do this with the class based views method.
When success_url is as above then it tries to redirect to the factuur.id with the deleted item.id what is not the wanted situation.

Comment: use can make list_view for `factuur` and redirect to list_view's url. because after deleting record there is no meaning for redirect to detail page

Comment: Actually i am deleting an item of factuur. Not the factuur itself. So I need to go back to the factuur itself to see the remaining items in the factuur.

Comment: What is the url that lists all the factuurs?

Comment: All factuurs: path('', views.facturen_view, name='facturen_view'),

Comment: single factuur: path('factuur/<factuur_id>', views.facturen_detail_view, name='facturen_detail_view'),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what is worth, I solved it with get_succes_url like this:

```
class FactuurItemDeleteView(BSModalDeleteView):
    model = FactuurItems
    template_name = 'delete_fitem.html'
    success_message = 'Succes: factuur item is verwijderd.'
    #success_url = reverse_lazy('facturen_detail_view')

    # Go to a success_url with argument=factuur_id
    def get_success_url(self):
        factuur_nr = self.get_object().item_factuur
        faktuurtje = Facturen.objects.get(factuurnummer=factuur_nr)
        faktuurtje_id = faktuurtje.id
        return reverse_lazy('facturen_detail_view', kwargs={'factuur_id': faktuurtje_id})
```